# Accessing the MSP and PSP registers of the Cortex-M3 in C/C++ code using Keil's µVision

Tags: embedded, cortex-m

I need to access the MSP and PSP registers (the main and process stack registers) of the Cortex-M3 processor.

I'm writing in C/C++.

The µVision and associated compiler doesn't let you do inline assembly for this Thumb-2 only core (and I'm not sure that'd be such a good idea anyway).

I need to do this so that I can extract the immediate value of an svc instruction regardless of whether it was executed while in thread or handler mode.

Thanks,

Comment: What makes you think you cannot do inline assembly? It is not the case.  uVision is the IDE, not the compiler.  It is used with either ARMCC v5, ARM Compiler v6 (LLVM/clang) or gcc; all of which support in line assembly.  The syntax differes between ARM Compiler and gcc. Perhaps you are trying to use gnu assembler syntax in ARM Compiler?

Comment: ARM compiler v5 and v6 inline assembly syntax: https://developer.arm.com/documentation/100068/latest/Migrating-from-armcc-to-armclang/Inline-assembly-with-Arm-Compiler-for-Embedded-6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have access to a Keil compiler at the moment to verify this, but according to the docs you should be able to use the compiler's "named register variable" feature:

```
register uint32_t msp __asm("msp");
register uint32_t psp __asm("psp");
```

- http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armccref/armccref_cjahjdbg.htm
- http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armcc/armcc_CHDHCIEE.htm

Comment: Thanks, Michael. I didn't realize that I could do inline assembly. The compiler refuses to do block inline assembly because that, apparently, requires Arm mode instructions and the Cortex-M3 only does Thumb-2.

Comment: A limitation of Keil, of course.  GCC allows inline assembly on Cortex-M3.

Comment: @DavidGrayson.  It is not true, it is not a limitation, and not specific to Keil. Since Keil was acuired by ARM, it uses ARM's compiler - proprietary up to v5, and LLVM/clang based from v6.  You can do inline assembly, just not using gnu syntax.  In line assembly is a compiler extension, there is no standard syntax for that; you have to read the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

For something like this I usually use a tiny assembly call-out to do it.

You can use the special register access instruction (MRS / MSR) to access either SP.  I think with uVision, the MSP is ***SP_main***, and the PSP is ***SP_process***.

My ARM assembly is a little rusty, but I think it'd be something like:

```
MRS   R0, SP_process   // R0 holds retval
BX    LR                // return
```

From your question, it seems that you already understand the distinction between the MSP & PSP, and know how to determine which one to read (via the LR).

Answer (score 0):

The CMSIS core library provides some inline functions (with inline assembler implementation) which allow access:
https://www.keil.com/pack/doc/CMSIS/Core/html/group__Core__Register__gr.html

Comment: The question and its earlier answers are from 13 yrs ago, maybe this improvement has only become possible in the meantime.